# cities of select box are not dynamically changing based on the selected state using jquery in my below code

Tags: php, jquery

Below is the Jquery code

```
$("#state").change(function(){
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "www.myweb.com/ajax.abc.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {state: function(){return $("#state").val()}}; /* i have given stateId as value*/
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $('#city').find('option').remove().end().append(html);
        } 
    });
```

below code is represented in the ajax file (i.e. ajax.abc.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['state']))
{

$getCity = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tblCity WHERE stateId = '.$_POST['state']);
while($fetchCity = mysql_fetch_array($getCity))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$fetchCity["cityName"].'">'.$fetchCity["cityName"].'</option>';
}

}
```

Comment: Are you getting into the `success`? Means your ajax call works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break this line:

```
$('#city').find('option').remove().end().append(html);
```

Into two parts:

```
$('#city').find('option').remove();
$('#city').append(html);
```

Right now, you are removing an `option`, but then calling `append` on it, which obviously won't work.